# Accepting null values despite if condition

Tags: vb.net

I want to save values to a MySQL database.

I made a check that the database should not insert null values. I have three textboxes and make check that if the textboxes values are null then display a message that null values are not acceptable.

The problem is that when I load the form firstly it work proper after pressing insert button but on the second time it accepts the null values which are inserted into database.

My code is:

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" And TextBox2.Text = "" And TextBox3.Text = "" And ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("please write data", "Input Error")
    TextBox1.Focus()
Else
    // my program body      
end if
```

But when I click the insert button second time it does not read the condition that the textboxes' values are null or not...

Comment: Can you share the complete code of button Click?

Comment: The debugger is your friend

Comment: You can do your validation in the `Validating` of the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the second time the values of the text boxes are empty, they may contain some white spaces. So you will have to trim the text in the Textboxes before using them, like in the code below. You should also change `And` to `Or` in your if statements else it won't execute except all the text boxes are empty.

```
 If Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" Or Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" Or Trim(TextBox3.Text) = "" Or Trim(ComboBox1.Text) = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("please write data", "Input Error")
    TextBox1.Focus()
 Else
  'my program body      
 end if
```

Comment: I think a useful improvement to this answer would be to mention the distinction between an empty string (sometimes referred to as a null string) and null as it is used in a database.

Answer (score 1):

Default Text property for TextBox is Empty String, not null value. That is not your case. In order to validate your data, you must replace the AND operator with OR, as @preciousbetine said.

If you use the AND operator, you'll need all Textboxes be Empty to return error.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `NULL` values into your database, you could `ALTER` your table too, and impose default values to your desired columns. Here's a example (for `SQL Server`):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TABLE  
ADD CONSTRAINT   A_CONSTRAINT DEFAULT 50 FOR YOUR_DESIRED_COLUMN ;
```